# Getting error 'org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, coordinates

**Json Response:-**

```
{
"type" : "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [ [ [ [
                -83.855020462486394,
                 36.800791838085125
            ], [
                -83.855122494686938,
                 36.800830858080204
            ], [
                -83.856076988974678,
                 36.801197800946333
            ], [
                -83.856471494201926,
                 36.801023860713194
            ], [
                -83.860159013544774,
                 36.799399831464761
            ]]]]
        }
    }
}
```

**Code:-**

```
val `object` = JSONObject(x)
val features = `object`.getJSONArray("features")
for (i in 0 until features.length()) {
val featureObject = features.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry")
if (featureObject.getString("type") == "MultiPolygon") {
    Log.e("@@@@","length...."+features.length())
   }
}


for (j in 0 until ((featureObject.getJSONArray("coordinates").get(0) as JSONArray).get(0) as JSONArray).length()) {

Log.e("coordinates@#@#", " "+((featureObject.getJSONArray("coordinates").get(0) as JSONArray).get(0) as JSONArray).get(j))

multiplePolyTempList.add(((featureObject.getJSONArray("coordinates").get(0) as JSONArray).get(0) as JSONArray).get(j) as Any)

Log.e("Anyy  ", "AnyyType ... "+((featureObject.getJSONArray("coordinates").get(0) as JSONArray).get(0) as JSONArray).get(j) as Any)

}
```

> Exceptionjava.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

Can someone please explain to me how to convert org.json.JSONArray convert to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng, I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey when having that last JsonArray that contains two double values. You can convert it to LatLng by extracting those double values and creating LatLng object. For example you can use the following helper function.

```
fun convertToLatLng(jsonArray: JSONArray): LatLng {
    val lat = jsonArray.getDouble(0)
    val lng = jsonArray.getDouble(1)
    return LatLng(lat, lng)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bongo, I will check and update you.

Comment: Bongo, It's working but I got the error, Could you please help me to resolve this?

`Failed to allocate a 4723 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 86MB until OOM, target footprint 471680928, growth limit 536870912; failed due to malloc_space fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 3376 bytes, space in use 59554648 bytes, capacity = 59695104)`